# drf-yasg Django restframework Swagger Page return 401 Unauthorized error

Tags: swagger, swagger-ui, drf-yasg

[image]

Hi!
I want to try out my API, but I can't access to Swagger page.
I don't know why it return 401 Unauthorized error.

Please let me know.
Thank you!

Comment: What configurations you've set for schema_view in urls.py module?